# Java How to validate 2 inputs are floats or not

Tags: java, validation, java.util.scanner, do-while

I am asking user to enter 2 floats and need to validate if user has correctly entered 2 floats. I am using 'Scanner' to read user's input, and using '.hasNextFloat()'to validate if user's input are floats or not.
My codes are as below. But i found out the codes i wrote will only validate the first input of user when first time running the do..while loop, so if user's input is (character + float) the codes can come out the correct result. But if the user's input is (float + character), then it will crash, because it will bypass the do..while loop, and go directly to **firstN = readInput1.nextFloat();secondN = readInput1.nextFloat();** Therefore, I want to know how can i check both input using the do...while loop.Thank you!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.printf("Welcome to Lucy's Get 2 Floats Program! \n\n");

    Scanner readInput1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    float firstN;
    float secondN;

    do
    {       
    System.out.println("Please enter two floats separated by a space: ");
    while(!readInput1.hasNextFloat()) {  
        System.out.println("You have entered an invalid choice. Please try again:");
      readInput1.next(); 
      readInput1.next();
    }
    } while(!readInput1.hasNextFloat());    

    firstN = readInput1.nextFloat();
    secondN = readInput1.nextFloat();
    System.out.printf("You have entered two valid floats: %5.2f and %5.2f", firstN, secondN);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works but I don't know if it is the best/most efficient way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.printf("Welcome to Lucy's Get 2 Floats Program! \n\n");

    Scanner readInput1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    float firstN;
    float secondN;

    System.out.println("Please enter two floats separated by a space: ");
    boolean loop = true;
    while(loop) {
        if (readInput1.hasNextFloat()) {
            firstN = readInput1.nextFloat();
            if (readInput1.hasNextFloat()) {
                secondN = readInput1.nextFloat();
                System.out.printf("You have entered two valid floats: %5.2f and %5.2f", firstN, secondN);
                loop = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("You have entered an invalid choice. Please try again:");
                readInput1.next();
            }
        } else {
            readInput1.next();
            readInput1.next();
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid choice. Please try again:");
        }
    }

}
```